# How to configure APIs for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-rest-api

I made a lambda function that calls an API and returns the content returned from said API in JSON format:

```
import json
import requests

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    URL = "https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/onelineaddress?address="
    URLB = "&benchmark=Public_AR_Census2020&vintage=Census2020_Census2020&layers=10&format=json"
    # print(event)
    # address = event["address"]
    address = "1111 Morse Ave Sunnyvale, CA 94089"
    req = requests.get(URL + address + URLB)
    data = req.text
    return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    'body': event
    }   
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

Right now I am having a peculiar issue: I can't seem to figure out how to link an API to it.

So I have 2 questions:

1. When I am configuring a REST API via the triggers menu, is there any special configuration I have to do with the API?
2. What format am I supposed to write the URL in to define `event['address']`?

thanks!

When I set the `address` variable to something constant, it works fine and returns the correct value.

When it is not, I get `{"message": "Internal server error"}` back from the API call.

I am pretty sure I need to include parameters in the API call but I don't know how.

Comment: Are you saying that you would like a URL that triggers the AWS Lambda function and passes-in information via `event`? Or are you wanting your code to **call** an API somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: I am trying to get a URL that triggers the Lambda function that passes information via event. I already have the API call done.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to trigger an AWS Lambda function via a URL.

There are two ways to do this:

- [Lambda function URLs - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html)
- [Build an API Gateway REST API with Lambda integration - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html)

Both methods allow parameters to be passed via the URL, which will be provided to the AWS Lambda function via the `event` parameter.